# Authenticated Invocation of API Gateway from Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, serverless

On the same AWS account, I have an *API Gateway* and a *Lambda*.

Access to *API Gateway* must be *authenticated* (Any sort of authentication).

Is there any way of achieving this **without manually setting headers on Lambda request**?

- What I've tried:

On API Gateway, under Settings for Authorization, I've set AWS_IAM.
On Lambda, I've added an IAM policy that allows all API invocation.

ref: https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/iam-authentication-api-gateway/

- Result:

No header is set, so requests are responding with "AuthMissingAuthenticationTokenException".

Comment: For python you would use [aws-requests-auth](https://github.com/DavidMuller/aws-requests-auth) to make valid IAM request to your gateway. For other programming languages, you have to find equivalents.

Comment: What kind of authentication you set for API gateway?

Comment: @Marcin this is what I'm trying to avoid ):

Comment: @hoangdv AWS_IAM

Comment: Sadly there is no other way. AWS_IAM requires requests with sigv4 aws signature. If you don't want AWS_IAM, then maybe set your API as private only, and invoke it without any authentication from lambda in a VPC?

Comment: Maybe no way, sign your request or attach the header. If your api gateway links to a lambda function, just call the function directly (just assign invoke permission for caller function.)

Comment: @Marcin, hoangdv well, at least I've tried (: Thanks